# Parallel reduction by key implementations

Tags: performance, c, cuda

I have an implementation of the reduction approach used in [this document](http://devblogs.nvidia.com/parallelforall/faster-parallel-reductions-kepler/). Furthermore, I extended (crudely) this so I can reduce-by-key.

In my setup I can assume that a `key` array variable is constant through subsequent calls to a reduction kernel and that it is sorted in increasing order, and can thus pre-process and make any assumptions about the reduction necessary. I can further assume that each individual `key` will only ever be seen at the block level and as such I do not need to consider reduction across blocks.

To extend the approach used in the above document, I have padded data (with `-1`) such that each warp only deals with a single `key` value, and then the results of each individual warp's reduction is atomically added to the output array. However, this is inefficient as I have to launch many times more threads that are really necessary, and most are inactive.

An example `key`:

> ```
> [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 ...
> ```

Below is the setup I have.

```
__global__ void reduce(int N, int* key, float* out)
  {
    int i = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + ti;
    if (i < N)
      {
        int ti = threadIdx.x;
        int li = ti % warpSize;

        // code which computes a value per thread to be reduced, 
        // for threads where key[i] == -1, val = 0.f
        float val = 123.45f;

        // reset out to zero ready for atomic addition later
        if (li == 0)
          out[key[i]] = 0.f;
        __syncthreads();

        // warp reduction
        int offset = 0;
        for (offset = warpSize / 2; offset > 0; offset /= 2)
          val += __shfl_down(val, offset);

        // atomically update out with each warp's result
        if (li == 0)
          atomicAdd(&out[key[i]], val);
      }
   }
```

What improvements could be appropriate for such a reduce-by-key implementation? For example, I think I should be using `__ballot` to only reduce those with keys matching a predicate, and could therefore remove my padding with `-1`s, although can't get my head around it to actually implement it.

Comment: I have actually gone through this myself now with time and am using warp shuffles. When I have time I will add an answer for future reference and others.

Comment: Please add your answer, it will be up voted. In the future keep in mind it is easier to do performance code reviews where there is more context, any performance issues might be in the code that calls this function.